# displaying org charts in meteor js app

Tags: javascript, meteor, charts, google-visualization

I have seen some options but I haven't tried trying thoroughly. But have you tried to generate an organizational chart in a meteor js app? If yes what libraries or packages did you use?

There are options to use chart js, but this does not include the org chart capability. My best bet is to use google charts but I'm still not 100% sure how I can make it work with meteor js.

Comment: Which frontend system / lib do you use? Why didn't you just try anything you found in your search engine to integrate?

Comment: I am using Blaze as the front end. Honestly, right now I am not sure how to integrate 3rd party libraries into meteor.

Comment: For others facing this scenario, I recommend https://github.com/rafaelhdr/meteor-google-charts. This is sufficient enough at least for my needs.

Comment: With Blaze it is very straight forward to integrate third party libraries that are already bundled and have to be rendered into a specific target. Start trying on your own with google charts and if you get stuck you can come back and extend this question with a more specific problem and we will be happy to help you.

Comment: thank you. yes I will further check on this.